# Can I use foreach loop to make Textarea

Tags: php, html

I am wondering if I can use `foreach` loop to generate textarea and also print values inside of the textarea. For example:

> Group 1: textarea here with some value inside
>
> Group 2: textarea here with some value inside

So let say I have this code to split and string and put into different group by length. How can I make textarea using foreach loop?

```
foreach($strArr as $v) {
    $result["Group ".strlen($v)][] = $v;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: just add `'echo <textarea>here your value</textarea>'` inside the foreach loop

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it now

Answer (score 0):

As PHP Developer said, you can echo html tags out and set the values inside the text area.

A simple example of this using a variable would be:

```
foreach ($result_array as $result) {
    echo '<textarea>'. $result .'</textarea>';
}
```